# Maps won't zoom out

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

As of the new update yesterday 1.92 on PS4 for Minecraft I can no longer zoom out on my maps. I created a new map and it is level 0/4. After placing the new map inside the crafting table surrounded by 8 pieces of paper, the map will not craft to a zoomed out version.

Comment: I don't want to answer my question because im still confused why I cannot zoom out my maps through the crafting table. However, I found when using a cartography table the map zooms out one level for each one piece of paper used. Solution figured out but question unsolved?

Comment: I am actually also confused. The recipe you described works on bedrock edition, however looks like ps4 is legacy edition? It is pretty confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make cartography table and add map to top left then add paper to bottom left then it will use 1 paper per zoom level when you pull it out of right side and then place it on top left to do again. Was kinda pissed about it myself and then I figured it out and I'm still not happy with it especially since when u make a map on the crafting table the normal way with 8 paper and a compass it stills open as a small map.

Comment: It doesn't really matter, even if you make a 4/4 map, the zoom feature doesn't seem to work properly.  I have tried this several times and the 4/4 map will not contain the area the original 0/4 map contained.  broke.